# Push values into another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have $caption_message that outputs this with a print_r:

```
[03-May-2017 14:40:43 UTC] label 1
[03-May-2017 14:40:44 UTC] label 2
[03-May-2017 14:40:44 UTC] label 3
```

Is there a way i can push this 3 values into a new array where they have 0,1,2 indexes? I've been trying with array_push and array_values but with no luck.

Comment: Please share your input and expected output clearly.

Comment: [0] -> label 1
[1] -> label 2
[2] -> label 3

Comment: `array_values($caption_message)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_values like this:

```
$new_array = array_values($caption_message);
print_r($new_array);
```

Or loop through the array and push values like this:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($caption_message as $message) {
  $new_array[] = $message;
  // Alternatively array_push($new_message, message);
}
print_r($new_array);
```

But it looks like you just want to copy the array so do this:

```
$new_array = $caption_message;
print_r($new_array);
```